# Removing an index element from a list

Tags: python, append, element

I'm trying to remove an element from list, but can only use the range function and append method (homework question). My 'for loop' when the index element position is not equal to the position parameter works fine. However I can't seem to get my if statements working correctly to the desired output. Any help would greatly appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
def length(my_list):

    result = 0
    for char in my_list:
        result += 1

    return result

def remove(my_list, position):

    new_list2 = [] # Create a new list
    length2 = length(my_list) # Calls upon the length function

    if position < 0:
        new_list2.append(my_list[position])

    for r in range(length2):
        if r != position:
            new_list2.append(my_list[r])

    if position > length2:
        (my_list)

    return new_list2

str_list5 = ['f','i','r','e']
new_list = remove(str_list5, 2)
print(new_list)
new_list = remove(str_list5, -1)
print(new_list)
new_list = remove(str_list5, 10)
print(new_list)
```

My output in particular position -1 and 10 should be:

```
['i','r','e']
['f','i','r']
```

Comment: Is there a reason you wrote your own `length()` function instead of just using the built-in `len()`?

Comment: What are you expecting `(my_list)` to do?

Comment: Can you explain why you expect those results with `-1` and `10`? `r != position` will always be true, so it will append all the list elements.

Comment: Why should `position = -1` produce the same result as `position = 0`?

Comment: Most list operations treat negative indexes as counting from the end, so `position = -1` should remove the last element, not the first.

Comment: Why should `position = 10` mean to remove the last element? What's the logic for that?

Comment: @Barmar I can't use the len()...I'm only allowed to use range and append. -1 and 10 were already given in the homework question as the position spots. Based on the code above I had to get the following outputs: ['f','i','e'], ['i','r','e'], '['f','i','r']. I got the first output through my loop, but I can't seem to get the other two.

Comment: Please edit the question to explain the logic that should be used for negative positions and positions larger than the length.

Comment: In general, if you can't explain what a program is supposed to do, you won't be able to program it. You have to understand the logic before you can write a program to implement it.

Comment: @Barmar This was the question: Write a function called remove_value(my_list, position) that takes a list and a remove_position as parameters.  The function returns a copy of the list with the item at the index specified by remove_position, removed from the list.  You must use a loop in your solution.  You may make use of the list_name.append(item) method in order to build the new list.  You must not use built-in functions (other than the range() function), slice expressions, list methods (other than the append() method) or string methods in your solution.

Comment: @Barmar Check for the remove-position value exceeding the list (my_list) bounds. 
-       If the position is greater than the length of the list, remove the item at the end of the list. 
-      If the position is less than or equal to zero, remove the item stored at the start of the list.

Comment: I said "Please edit the question". Important details should not be in comments.

Answer (score 0):

From the discussion, I gather that `position` values out of range are supposed to remove the nearer end character.  If so, then you need to do that "clip to the rail" logic properly, and before you do your normal single-character removal:

```
# A negative position means to remove the first char
if position < 0:
    position = 0
# A large position means to remove the last char
elif position >= length2:
    position = length2 - 1

# With that done, your existing "skip one char" logic should finish the job
for r in range(length2):
    if r != position:
        new_list2.append(my_list[r])
```

Comment: Great thanks @Prune . I can see where I was going wrong. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could write a function like this one:

```
def remove(string, i):
    length = len(string)
    if i > len(string):
        i =  i // length
    elif i < 0:
        i = len(string) - 1
    print([x for index, x in enumerate(string) if index != i])

str_list5 = ['f','i','r','e']   
remove(str_list5, 2)
['f', 'i', 'e']
```

With *negative* index:

```
remove(str_list5, -1)
['f', 'i', 'r']
```

How about this one?

```
myturn = ['this was cool']
remove(*myturn, 6)
['t', 'h', 'i', 's', ' ', 'w', 's', ' ', 'c', 'o', 'o', 'l']
```